# how to make a user upload private key file before any transaction in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ca

I understand that Hyperledger stores private key of users in a directory called keystore. i don't want my network to store it rather user should upload this file before any transaction. 
How to do it.

Comment: This is not really related to HLF itself. Moreover, this would cause some security issues and would require to trust users on key management, which may not be a good idea.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain IBM cloud doesn't store user private keys then how they are able to do it ?

Comment: You can retrieve identities private key/public key from IBM cloud. For example, using the nodejs SDK, use the admin identity and enroll the identity you want.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain yes when i enroll the identity that i want, it stores it's private key in the msp/keystore/ directory. when i delete it the transaction throws error . I want to achieve the functionality to make user enter the private key while transactionor upload the file. Please guide me how to do that thing ?

Comment: Just put a file upload on your front end and send it with your request?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Thanks for your quick response brother. could you please tell me how to append the private key with the request. My understanding so far is that i should set the user context just before the transaction has to be signed and ask user to upload the private key to confirm transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a full code to provide to you and I don't have time to write it. However, here is a flow you can follow:

- FRONT END: Allow user to upload files (Example (assuming you are building a web application): http://reusableforms.com/d/o3/html5-contact-form-with-file-upload)
- BACK END: Retrieve the file from the request.
- BACK END: Create the user context from these files
- BACK END: Build/send transaction
- FABRIC: Process transaction
- BACK END: If transaction is VALID, delete all the information about the user (private key in particular)
- BACK END: Send response back to FRONT END

---

I do not know what is your scenario, but:

- I think having the user manage its own keys is a risk, as he can lose it or someone may "hack" the user device to get it.
- Having private keys moving on the network may be a security issue, has someone may be able to intercept it.

But as I said, I don't know your scenario. If you are in a closed network then transfering PK **might** not be a problem. If your client application manages the keys for the user, it may be ok too, but what if the user deletes it by mistake? Or what if the device is broken?

Comment: For that purpose we will store the user private key on his cluster of nodes as in my scenario every user will treated as a separate organization and to show user that his transaction is secure , i want users to upload private key at the time of transaction because this feature will help me in marketing it and my network is a closed network. I was also thinking the same thing after your last reply but thank you so much for your precious time brother. 
You're doing a great job.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding of what the keystore folder accomplishes and what you want to accomplish here.

In the context of an MSP, the keystore folder does store private keys. It stores the private keys of the identities represented by the MSP. However, this is highly unique to the node that the MSP is running on.

On a peer, the keystore would store the certificate for the peer and the key for the peer identity. It would not store the keys for any other identity, as that node is not meant to act as that identity (remember that ownership of private = able to act as that identity). It would also store the certificates (not private keys) of the identities meant to act as administrators of that peer.

What exactly are you trying to do by allowing users to upload the private key? If you are trying to allow users to identify themselves to the network, providing their key is not the solution. If it's something else, try and edit your post to explain your use case more clearly so we can help.